# cannot reach backend modules; routing problem

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I have a symfony application (version 1.4 ) and I created backend application and modules in it. But can't reach them. I want to reach the modules with a link like:

projectname/management/main

projectname is an alias, already set in wamp server and works properly in frontend.
management is just a tag to specify that we are in backend part.
main is a module as a homepage of backend app.
Inside of routing.yml (C:\wamp\www\projectname\apps\backend\config\routing.yml) is:

```
homepage:
  url:   /:management
  param: { module: main, action: index }

# generic rules
# please, remove them by adding more specific rules
default_index:
  url:   /management/:module
  param: { action: index }

default:
  url:   /management/:module/:action/*
```

But it gives "Page Not Found-404" error.Where is the mistake or is there any extra thing I should do, thanks for help..

Answer (score 0):

You created two application. What is the real path of the related "front-controller" files?

**Frontend**

I suppose:

- path: C:\wamp\www\projectname\web\index.php
- url: http://projectname

Is it right?

**Backend**

What about backend?

> - 1) C:\wamp\www\projectname\web\management\index.php
> - 2) C:\wamp\www\projectname\web\backend.php

*Case 1:*

url: http://projectname/management/index.php

(You can omit "index.php" if .htaccess is configured properly, obviously.)

routing.yml:

```
homepage:
  url:   /
  param: { module: main, action: index }

default_index:
  url:   /:module
  param: { action: index }

default:
  url:   /:module/:action/*
```

*Case 2:*

url: http://projectname/backend.php/management

routing.yml:

```
homepage:
  url:   /management
  param: { module: main, action: index }

default_index:
  url:   /management/:module
  param: { action: index }

default:
  url:   /management/:module/:action/*
```

Comment: this url(http://projectname/backend.php/management) works, thanks:) but how can I achive to reach via "http://projectname/management" ?

Comment: You have to set up the first case. "management" must be a real directory. Let me know.